# MongoDefaults.MaxConnectionIdleTime in php driver

Tags: php, mongodb

We need to set the option MongoDefaults.MaxConnectionIdleTime in php driver.

Can someone point me to how i may be able to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing in the PHP driver.

Most other MongoDB drivers use connection pooling, and allow you to keep "spare open connections in the pool". However, the PHP driver does not have a shared connection pool, therefore making this configuration option irrelevant.